# what is the right way to use `material-icons`?

Tags: material-design, material-ui

I am using `material-ui` in my react project. I found there are two different ways to use their icons.

One is from this web site: https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=3d_rotation&style=baseline. You can download the icon on the left panel by click it. Or you can install `material-design-icons` on your project.

Another way is to import them like:

```
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import ArrowDownwardIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowDownward';
import Close from '@material-ui/icons/Close'
```

I wonder are they same? Or what is the different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Material-UI, the way I (and they) suggest to use them is with SVGIcons, the `@material-ui/icons` package. What I typically do is look up icons on that website you posted and pull them in from `@material-ui/icons`.

For example, on that website you'll see one called `alarm_on` well you import it from that package like `import YourIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AlarmOn'`.

And the reason I like to do this and not use Icon Fonts is because when people with bad connections try to load your app, the icon might not even load and they'll see an ugly "alarm_on" in plain text where the icon would be.

[Take a look at the usage section here.](https://material-ui.com/components/icons/)